# Prove that $H$ is not a subspace of the $C(-\infty, \infty)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Show that $$H = \{f(x)\, | \, f \in C(-\infty, \infty) \land f(x) \geq 0\, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ is not a subspace of $C(-\infty,\infty)$.

I know that to be a subspace $H$ needs three things:

- $H$ needs to include the zero vector
- $H$ needs to be closed under vector addition
- $H$ needs to be closed under multiplication by scalars

However I am lost when reading the question. I don't even understand the notation. Any help is welcome.

Comment: What is it that you do not understand about the notation?

Comment: The carrot in the middle and the upside-down A

Comment: The $|$ in the middle means “such that” and $\forall$ means “for all”.

Comment: The $\forall$ means for all, the $\wedge$ means "and" the $\mid$ means "such that"

Comment: I've updated the text to include your question as it was written in the pic.  I actually think $$H = \{f \in C(-\infty, \infty) \, | \, f(x) \geq 0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ is a better definition, though...

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm in a better spot now that I understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f\neq 0\in H$ implies $-f\notin H$, it is not a subspace.

Comment: Your implication isn't entirely true, but it doesn't matter, since you only need one $f \in H$ such that $-f \not\in H$ and it's not hard to find one.

Comment: Could someone explain this and why it doesn't meet the three subspace rules?

Comment: @Brian you are right. I tweaked it.

Comment: @hulloWurld it's not closed under scalar multiplication. Look at $f(x)=x^2$. Note $f\in H$, but $(-1\cdot f)(x)=-x^2$ is not in $H$.

Comment: Thank you all for the help!